# how to set the apk release file name using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use 'generate signed APK' to create release apk on android studio.
Android studio create apk with name 'app-release.apk'

I want to set my name to this apk and i don't find any way to do it.

Comment: just rename it .

Comment: can't ... if i rename it the sign fail and i can't install it from this apk

Answer (score 1):

In `build.gradle' file:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionCode 4
        versionName "App name 1.x"
        project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to that

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", "apk_name")
```

and another way is

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        project.ext { appName = 'MyAppName' }
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
        def newName = output.outputFile.name
        newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-")
        newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release" + formattedDate)
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
    }
}
```